# Вытащить oleobject из excel

Tags: c#, excel

Есть exсel-файл, в который с помощью макроса `getPhotoSheet().OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strPath, DisplayAsIcon:=True).Top`
(где getPhotoSheet() - получение нужной страницы, strPath - путь к файлу) заносятся изображения.
Необходимо выгрузить эти изображения и сохранить в папку. Я нашел два способа:

1. Сохранение документа как html страницу;
2. Работа через Shapes: сначала копируем объект в chart, затем этот chart уже сохраняем куда нам надо.

Но эти оба способа не работают - вместо картинки сохраняется изображения ярлыка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно вытащить изображение? Я пишу приложение на c#, использую библиотеку Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, задача довольно нетривиальная, т.к. напрямую извлечь содержимое встроенного объекта нельзя.

Но можно придумать обходной путь через копирование объекта в буфер обмена. Данные копируются в буфер в некоем бинарном формате, описания которого мне найти не удалось. Однако, он не слишком сложен и его можно разобрать. Не уверен, что код будет работать абсолютно всегда (я тестировал на Excel 2013), но как минимум он дает направление решения:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    app.Visible = false;

    var book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\book.xlsx");
    Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[1];

    // перебираем все встроенные объекты
    OLEObjects objects = sheet.OLEObjects();
    foreach (OLEObject obj in objects) {
        Clipboard.Clear();
        obj.Copy(); // копируем встроенный объект в буфер обмена
        SaveObject(@"d:\tmp"); // сохраняем объект в каталог
    }

    book.Close();
    app.Quit();
}

static void SaveObject(string dirToSave)
{
    // буфер обмена не содержит данные в нужном виде - выходим
    if (!Clipboard.ContainsData("Native")) {
        return;
    }

    // получаем данные из буфера в виде MemoryStream
    // стрим содержит некую бинарную структуру данных, включая строенный в объект файл
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(Clipboard.GetData("Native") as MemoryStream)) {
        // сначала идут два байта с чем-то непонятным
        reader.ReadInt16();

        // затем подряд имя встроенного файла
        // и полный путь к оригинальному файлу.
        // строки в стиле С (ограничены '\0')
        var fileName = ReadNullString(reader);
        var origFileName = ReadNullString(reader);

        // затем идут 8 байт непонятного назначения
        reader.ReadInt64();

        // полное имя временного файла, куда будет выгружен файл,
        // если по ней дважды щелкнуть в окне Excel
        var tmpFileName = ReadNullString(reader);

        // затем идет размер файла
        var fileSize = reader.ReadInt32();

        // сохраняем файл
        var saveTo = Path.Combine(dirToSave, fileName);
        using (var fs = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create)) {
            var block = new byte[4096];
            int read = 0;
            do {
                int r = reader.Read(block, 0, 4096);
                fs.Write(block, 0, Math.Min(4096, fileSize - read));
                read += r;
            } while (read < fileSize);
        }
    }
}

static string ReadNullString(BinaryReader reader)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    byte tmp;

    while ((tmp = reader.ReadByte()) != 0) {
        result.Append((char)tmp);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```